# override multiple properties defined in multiple files at once, including @Qualifier Properties properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

So, I got a very chaotic legacy project to work on, it is stuck in **spring-boot.version 2.5.13**.

The main has the import resource tag, similar to this

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:app-context.xml")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.class, ValidationAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

the **app-context.xml** has the property-placeholder imports

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:application.properties,file:ext/application.properties,classpath:somemodule.properties" />
<import resource="classpath:app-scope.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:app-this.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:app-that.xml" />
```

and each file has its on import like

```
moduleX.properties.location=etc/morepropertiesX.properties
moduleY.properties.location=config/morepropertiesY.properties
moduleZ.properties.location=morepropertiesZ.properties
```

so, it is bleeding configuration all over the place, some .yaml, some .properties, some .xml...

So, I couldn't find a way to just have one file, maybe a profile or something, that I could change all properties needed at once, something that I can just add to the ignore list on git, or maybe have an external arg on the IDE runner.

I tried making use of the the default properties like this

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:appl-context.xml")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.class, ValidationAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Main.class);

        java.util.Map<String, Object> localProperties = new java.util.HashMap<>();
        localProperties.put("someProperty.A", "some value A");
        localProperties.put("someProperty.B", "some value B");
        localProperties.put("someNewPropertyTest", "some new value");
        app.setDefaultProperties(localProperties);

        app.run(args);
        //SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

this would allow to have the changes only here, or maybe a new class and only point to that class, and add it to the ignore list on git. But the existing properties values are still there, not being overridden and the new property still NULL. So checking the class that I was trying to inject the properties, it reads it with @Qualifed property name :(

something like this

```
@Component
public class SomeClass{
    public SomeClass(@Qualifier(value = "somemodule.properties") final Properties properties) {
        final String propertyA = properties.getProperty("someProperty.A"));
        final String propertyB = properties.getProperty("someProperty.B"));
        final String newProperty = properties.getProperty("someNewPropertyTest"));
        /**......**/
    }
}
```

so in this case, the property A and B still holds the value defined on the property file itself, and the new property just returns null as it does not exists on the original file.

Any ideas on how to have those properties overridden, even with the @Qualifier annotation?
It doesn't need to be pretty, just need to make life easier, specially when we have to change people on the team, it is always a nightmare to go over all gazilion configuration files

Comment: Did you mean Spring**Boot** 2.5? Spring (Framework) 2.5 was released in 2007 and the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation is from Spring Boot 1.0, which at least appeared in 2012 according to the dates in the license. (Just to make sure the tags are correct)

Comment: good catch, I put the wrong tag, I'll update it, thanks